# Configuring My PHP

Tags: php, forms, twitter-bootstrap

Hey I am trying to figure out my problem with my form and where my hangups are in the code. Anyone have any suggestions?

```
<form method="post" action="tourney.php">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Name" name="tname">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Email" name="temail">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="School or Club" name="tclub">
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Address" name="taddress">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="City" name="tcity">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="State" name="tstate">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Zip" name="tstate">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <textarea placeholder="Type your message here..." class="form-control" rows="5"></textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <select name="type" class="form-control">
                            <OPTION VALUE="None Selected" SELECTED>Please select one</OPTION>
                            <OPTION VALUE="Middle School">Middle School Tournamanet</OPTION>
                            <OPTION VALUE="Elementary">Elementary Tournament</OPTION>
                        </select>
                    </div>



                    <div class="col-sm-6 pull-right">
                        <input class="btn btn-danger" type="submit" value="Register">
                    </div>
                </div>


            </form>
```

and the PHP to send the email:

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$from = "minguswrestling.com";
$to = "puremeld@gmail.com";
$name = $_POST['tname'];
$email = $_POST['temail'];
$school = $_POST['tclub'];
$address = $_POST['taddress'];
$city = $_POST['tcity'];
$state = $_POST['tstate'];
$zip = $_POST['tzip'];
$type = $_POST['type'];
$message = $_POST['tmessage'];
$subject = "Tourney Signup!";

$body = "From: $from \n Name: $name \n Email: $email \n School: $school\n Address: $address\n City: $city State: $state Zip: $zip\n Event: $type\n Message: $message";

if ($_POST['submit']) {
if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) {
    '<h2>Thank You!</h2>';
header("Location: index.html");
} else { 
    echo '<p>Oops! An error occurred. Try sending your message again.      </p>'; 
}
}
}
?>
```

Any help would be appreciated. I am using bootstrap for my build, thank you.

Comment: you're outputting before header for one thing. Then this will never happen `if(isset($_POST['submit'])){...}`

Comment: who doesn't have error checking\display on? it's you OP

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: Trying to gather information form my form and send it via email. Just not the best at it.

Comment: I am teaching myself so I get the sarcasm, but sometimes you gotta ask

Comment: ok, supper time; gotta run. La mia madre fatta la megliore lasagne!!

Comment: *"who doesn't have error checking\display on? it's you OP"* - No, it's *"moi"*. It costs too much @Dagon

Comment: Who doesn't love lasagne

Comment: Exactly @DustinCoressel lasagne is *sempre delizioso!*. I posted something for you below, *give that a whirl* ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things wrong with your code.

Firstly, and as I mentioned in comments; everything inside the following conditional statement will never fire up:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){...}
```

because there is no form element that is named "submit", being your submit button and error reporting would have thrown you an `undefined index submit notice...`.

Therefore you need to modify it to read as:

```
<input name="submit" class="btn btn-danger" type="submit" value="Register">
```

However, you have a second `if ($_POST['submit']) {` that needs to be removed; it's not needed.

You also have no name attribute for:

```
 <textarea placeholder="Type your message here..." class="form-control" rows="5"></textarea>
```

that needs to be modified to and adding `name="tmessage"` since `$message = $_POST['tmessage'];` is most likely to be used for the message:

```
 <textarea name="tmessage" placeholder="Type your message here..." class="form-control" rows="5"></textarea>
```

Also, you've used the same name here for both "state" and "zip":

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Zip" name="tstate">
```

which should read as:

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Zip" name="tzip">
```

Then, you're outputting before header having the `'<h2>Thank You!</h2>';` and header:

Sidenote: You may have meant to do `echo '<h2>Thank You!</h2>';`, yet that would still constitute as outputting before header, because PHP is actually throwing you a parse error, but your server is probably not set up to catch and display notices/errors etc.

```
if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) {
    '<h2>Thank You!</h2>';
header("Location: index.html");
}
```

You need to choose from "one" of those and not both. Either modify `'<h2>Thank You!</h2>';` to read as `echo '<h2>Thank You!</h2>';` and remove the header, or remove the "Thank you" and use header.

Consult the following on Stack about outputting before header:

- [How to fix "Headers already sent" error in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php)

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Displaying errors should only be done in staging, and never production.

Here's a rewrite and see the embedded comments:

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $from = "minguswrestling.com";
    $to = "puremeld@gmail.com";
    $name = $_POST['tname'];
    $email = $_POST['temail'];
    $school = $_POST['tclub'];
    $address = $_POST['taddress'];
    $city = $_POST['tcity'];
    $state = $_POST['tstate'];
    $zip = $_POST['tzip'];
    $type = $_POST['type'];
    $message = $_POST['tmessage'];
    $subject = "Tourney Signup!";

    $body = "From: $from \n Name: $name \n Email: $email \n School: $school\n Address: $address\n City: $city State: $state Zip: $zip\n Event: $type\n Message: $message";

if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) {
    echo '<h2>Thank You!</h2>'; // either use echo
// header("Location: index.html"); // or header, not both. Comment one or the other out.
} else {
    echo '<p>Oops! An error occurred. Try sending your message again.      </p>'; 
}

}
else { echo "Submit is not set."; }
?>
```

---

**Footnotes:**

It would be best to also use `!empty()` against your POST arrays, since anyone could use your form and pass empty values.

Reference:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php

Plus, `$from = "minguswrestling.com";` be careful with that. `mail()` expects that to be an E-mail address and not a domain and may end up in Spam.

Best to use a `From:` as stated in the manual.

**Consult the manual:**

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

---

**Final notes.**

It's unclear if you're using this from your own PC or a hosted service.

If it's from your own PC, then a Webserver needs to be installed and properly configured, including PHP and mail.

If from a hosted service, make sure that mail is made available to you.

Check your Spam also when testing.

If you're going to use header, add `exit;` for it, otherwise your code may want to continue executing:

```
header("Location: index.html");
exit;
```

Remember not to use the "echo" if you're going to use header.

Comment: Wow thank you my man. I appreciate the knowledge drop.

Comment: @DustinCoressel You're welcome Dustin. I hope this gets you success. I did make a few more edits, so you may need to reload my answer. If it did solve it, you could mark it as solved. You're not obligated to, but it informs everyone that a solution was found. *Welcome to Stack*, cheers.

Comment: It did work, but better I learned what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

The following:

```
'<h2>Thank You!</h2>';
header("Location: index.html");
```

Is wrong, you cannot output anything before a header. Remove:

```
'<h2>Thank You!</h2>';
```